# data validation that will return multiple values through vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a data validation that will return multiple values from a table.
I used vlookup func to make this, however is there a shorter way to make this without having a different formula apply to each cells..

vlookup used in each cells

```
B2: =VLOOKUP($A$2, $G$1:$J$7, 2,FALSE)
C2: =VLOOKUP($A$2, $G$1:$J$7, 3,FALSE)
D2: =VLOOKUP($A$2, $G$1:$J$7, 4,FALSE)
```

[myExcel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTr1t.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also try Index/Match instead of Vlookup in this case.

In B2

```
=INDEX(H:H,MATCH($A2,$G:$G,0))
```

and copy across.

Comment: thank you so much for your respond..it really helps..:)

Comment: @DylanMecagami this one is good too, I was going to recommend looking in to index match, but kept `vlookup()` to keep in line with your original formula. This one is better because, if you haven't noticed yet, you can easily swap columns/column headers around and don't have to update the formula. Whereas my answer you'd have to adjust it if your headers in the two table aren't in the same order. Nice answer sktneer!

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for liking the answer. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do it. Keeping with `VLOOKUP()`, a quick change is to use `column()`:
`=VLOOKUP($A$2, $G$1:$J$7, column(),FALSE)`

Since you appear to have `2` in column 2, in any cell in column B if you use `=Column()`, it'll return `2`.